# How to UV unwrap holodeck model

Tags: uv

I'd like to create a holodeck like this in Blender:

[image]

The holodeck model used is from [g3d](http://g3d.cs.williams.edu/g3d/data10/common/model/holodeck/holodeck.zip). The screenshot is simply the obj file and a material applied to it. What's interesting is that the grid lines align nicely, even at the rounded corners.

The model itself seems to be a simple box with beveled corners (don't mind the door). A simple square texture over it:

[image]

Question: How is that kind of model and texture created in Blender? My guess is that the "magic" of the alignment is in the UV map. However, the uv map looks like this:

[image]

How can you create such a UV map in Blender, so that the square material texture fits so nicely on the walls and even on the rounded corners? None of the in-built UV unwrapping techniques seem to lead to the desired result.

I only need to know how to create that UV map (if it's the key to achieve that result). I do know how to model and texture it.

Comment: Have you tried *follow active quads*?

Comment: Yes, didn't give me the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview:

[image: Final]

It's fairly simple setup but there is a little thing you should be aware of at the start. **Proportions of your model** should be even or squared (I'm not sure how to put it). In this example it's a box 1x2x0.8m. When you put something like 1.12x2.43x0.63m pattern will not create perfect grid. Also remember to **Apply Scale** of your mesh.

### Mesh and Seams:

[image: mesh]

> First of all it's a bad topology (ngons) but I've leaved it as is for
>   simplicity sake.

1. For beveled corners you should use even number of **Faces** to have an **Edge** in the center of them.
2. **Mark Seams** in a way to cut off walls, floor and ceiling.

### UV Map:

[image: uv]

1. Select all and **Unwrap** the mesh (<kbd>U</kbd> > **Unwrap**).
2. Go to **Image Editor**, select **UV Islands** one by one (<kbd>L</kbd> while hovering over an island) and **Snap** them to the cursor by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > **Selected to Cursor (Offset)**.

[image]

You can rotate islands that are vertically placed if you want but it's not necessary.

### Lining up grid:

There are two methods to line up grid and resize it (I don't know how to do it perfectly).

1. You can just select all **UV Islands** and **Scale** them up/down.
2. You can use **Mapping** node to set the grid size. I've used this method.

[image]

### Blend file:

[image]